# Image not found after building kivy by pyinstaller

Tags: kivy, pyinstaller

My kivy app runs ok after built by pyinstaller, however, some images (e.g. minus.png) seems not packaged as expected, even I have added them by using`--add-data`.

As can be seen, there is an error message that is minus.png not found in the terminal output (posted below).

Someone please help check if something error.
Thanks so much

This is my spec file

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('images\\billiards-icon-7.png', '.\\images'), ('images\\minus.png', '.\\images'), ('billiardsclub.kv', '.')],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
    [],
    name='billiards',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
    icon=['images\\billiards-icon-7.ico'],
)
```

And this is my terminal when running the app

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\bida\.kivy\logs\kivy_23-04-26_9.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\bida\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI160762\kivy\__init__.pyc"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\bida\PycharmProjects\billiards\dist\billiards.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 - Build 31.0.101.2114'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 - Build 31.0.101.2114'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <.\images\minus.png>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <.\images\minus.png>
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <.\images\minus.png>
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <.\images\minus.png>
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <.\images\minus.png>
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <.\images\minus.png>
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <.\images\minus.png>
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <.\images\minus.png>
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <.\images\minus.png>
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <.\images\minus.png>
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <.\images\minus.png>
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <.\images\minus.png>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
```

Comment: Try changing `('images\\minus.png', '.\\images')` to `('images/minus.png', 'images')`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because in your source code you are using relative paths from the current working directory to access the images, however once compiled with pyinstaller your images are no longer located in the same relative position to your current working directory.

Instead you need to make changes in your source code to get the images relative to your source files themselves.

For example if your project directory looks something like:

```
- app.py
- app.kv
- images
    | - minus.png
    | - billiards-icon-7.png
```

and in your app.py you are referencing the images with `./images/minus.png`, then you would instead need to change it to something like

```
import os

#  minus_img = "./images/minus.png" # <-- this doesn't work

root = os.path.dirname(__file__)
minus_img = os.path.join(root, "images", "minus.png")
```

Comment: Thanks, bro. I think you are correct, let me change it as your recommendation